# cypress error while testing file upload to api

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, cypress

I am testing an api which requires to send an image in the request body but I am getting error,

Here's my code:

```
it("should register a new litigant/customer", () => {
    cy.fixture('testImg1.png', "base64").then(base64 => {
        const blob = Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(base64, 'image/png')
        const bodyObj = {
            email: "customer@customer.com",
            password: "123456789",
            profilePicture: blob
        }
        let formData = new FormData()
        for (let key in bodyObj){
            formData.append(key, bodyObj[key])
        }
        cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: endpoints.signup.litigant,
            headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            body: formData,
        }).then(res => {
              expect(...)
        })
    })
})
```

But I am getting this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this??